# What do I should use for saving a text like a pdf in gdscript

Tags: pdf, save, godot, gdscript

I want to make a multi-device software with godot engine and I want to make it as lite as I can, so I just want to use a Line edit node and a button for saving the text but, is there any way to save it as .txt and .pdf files with code or I need an extra plugin?

Comment: Strick's answer is good, but I suggest you also research a bit about what a JSON file is. Depending on what you are doing, a JSON file can help you more easily manage your data. If you ever need to read your data back into your app, JSON is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing a plain text file is relatively easy:

```
var file = File.new()
file.open("user://some_file.txt", File.WRITE)
file.store_string("Some text")
file.close()
```

PDF is more difficult. I don't think that there are any out of the box solutions. But remember that PDF is also just a text file with specific commands embedded into the text. You would have to study the specifications of a PDF file and then generate the required structures yourself via the method described above.

Comment: and what about .txt Is it possible to save it as txt?

Comment: @MarsupialEntertainment I gave you an example of how to save a txt file in my answer.